# destructor of template class with pointer

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, destructor

I have a question.
Consider this template class

```
template<class T> 
class nodo{
public:
    T data;
};
```

Let's suppose that I'm not redefining the destructor. If we suppose that T=int, the standard destructor deallocates data. But what happens if T=int* ? Is just the pointer going to be deallocated  or the object pointed too? In theory just the pointer.

How can I deallocate the object pointed to? 
In the end, how can I write the destructor of a template class that has a template parameter that could be a pointer (and so of an explicit deallocation)?

Comment: easy fix, make `T` be `unique_ptr<int>` instead. Then the pointed-to object is automatically destroyed

Comment: It's no different than had you done `class nodo { public: int* data;}`.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x ,                 unique_ptr   works even if data is not a pointer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best option is to use `std::unique_ptr<int>` or `std::shared_ptr<int>` as the template argument, i.e. use

```
nodo<std::unique_ptr<int>> n1;
```

instead of

```
nodo<int*> n1;
```

You can try something like:

```
// Noop deleter
template <typename T> struct deleter
{
   void operator()(T& ptr) {}
};

// deleter that does something
template <typename T> struct deleter<T*>
{
   void operator()(T* ptr) { delete ptr; }
};


template<class T> 
class nodo{
public:
   using deleter_t = deleter<T>;
    T data;

    ~nodo()
    {
       deleter_t()(data);
    }
};
```

However, then you have to worry about another can of worms. What happens when `nodo` is copy-constructed or assigned to another `nodo` object? You need to take care of all the issues that make [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) and [The Rule of Five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11) relevant.

Comment: @CodeBott, use `nodo<int>` for nodes of type `int`. Use `nodo<std::unique_ptr<int>>` instead of `node<int*>` when the nodes are meant to hold pointers.

Comment: It looks very nice! I'll try, Thx

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a partially specialized template for pointer types:

```
template<typename T> class Test {
  T  val;
public:
  Test(T const &v) : val(v) {}
};

// Specialize for pointers
template<typename T> class Test<T*> {
  T* val;
public:
  Test(T* v) : val(v) {}
  ~Test() { delete  val; }
};
```

Comment: At least prohibit copying of the class when T is a pointer. Otherwise you will have UB if class is ever copied.